# Google Excution API not accepting long json

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm sending data to Google Execution API - I've got function in scripts to get parameter in json and put it in new Google Sheet. With small data it is working without a problem but I have big data to export - For example JSON that is sent in problematic export has 580k lines when formatted like this:

```
[
     {
        "productionDate": "12/08/2016",
        "legacyCode": null,
        "quantity": 1,
        "customer": "tst1",
        "customerAddress": "add1",
        "addressLegacyCode": "AD1"
    },
    {
        "productionDate": "12/08/2016",
        "legacyCode": null,
        "quantity": 1,
        "customer": "cust2",
        "customerAddress": "add1",
        "addressLegacyCode": "AD2"
    }
]
```

Does anyone of you know if there is a specific limit for length of parameter to be send to google.

I'm getting error:

```
[16-08-12 09:45:01:364 CEST] Starting execution
[16-08-12 09:45:01:373 CEST] Execution failed: Script function not found:  [0 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: the quotas and limits are documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas Anyway, not sure if that is your problem. Are you 100% sure the JSON structure is free from any error, and your Google Execution API has proper error handling for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes the data was too long to be included in parameters send to Google API.

I just wanted to point that out because the error message isn't clear whats failing.